# Need help to decide a game strategy

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I'd like to know what strategy should be used to solve the following problem.

### Problem Statement

There are 2 coal mines, each employing a group of miners. Our job is to send food shipments to the mines. Every time a shipment of food arrives at their mine, the miners produce some amount of coal. There are three types of food shipments: meat, fish and bread.

Every time a new shipment arrives to their mine, they will consider the new shipment and the previous two shipments (or fewer if there haven't been that many) and then:

- If all shipments are of the same type, they will produce one unit of coal
- If there are two different types of food among the shipments, they will produce two units of coal.
- If there are three different types of food, they will produce three units of coal.

The types of food shipments and the order in which they will be sent is known beforehand.

### Input

You are given the types of food shipments, in the order in which they are to be sent.

### Goal

The goal is to maximize the coal output. This is done by determining which shipment should go to which mine. The 2 mines don't necessarily have to receive the same number of shipments (in fact, it is permitted to send all shipments to one mine).

### Example

For the shipment order: MBMFFB, the expected output (maximum possible coal output) is 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you use is wrong:

```
M -> Mine 1 = 1 coal unit(s)

B -> Mine 1 = 2 "

M -> Mine 2 = 1 "

F -> Mine 1 = 3 "

F -> Mine 2 = 2 "

B -> Mine 2 = 3 "
```

Since for the first day, Mine 1 only had 1 type of food.

I can see a simple dynamic programming algorithm, but I'll leave that to you.

A simple hint: for each shipment, you can send it to either mine 1 or 2; after sending it, what matters is just:

1. The amount of mine that has been mined;
2. The previous 3 shipments.

So there are at most (3 ^ 3) ^ 2 = 729 shipment configurations, and for each of these an optimal amount of coal. In each step compute these configurations, and in the end you will get the answer.

Comment: But can you please at least hint me towards the algorithm? I am still learning various algorithmic techniques.

Comment: @ParthThakkar Edited. You might also want to edit the question a bit to extract its core information, so that more people might see this and provide you more answers (and more reps to the both of us).